# Everytime i run my code i get TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Tags: python, json

```
[2022-08-09 15:45:53,741] ERROR in app: Exception on /canary/live_birds [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/bin/auth_functions.py", line 52, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/views/canaries/view.py", line 25, in live_birds
    vm = Canaries()
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/viewmodels/canaries/canaries_viewmodel.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.get_live_birds()
  File "/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/ssd_dashboard/app/viewmodels/canaries/canaries_viewmodel.py", line 35, in get_live_birds
    y = json.loads(response_json)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
```

My code:

```
def get_live_birds(self):
    r = requests.get(self.baseurl+"/devices/live", params=self.payload)
    response_json = r.json()
    y = json.loads(response_json)
    print(y)
```

I cant seem to figure out how to convert my r.json() to a string, can someone pleaaaase help!!!

r.json() is an output of https://docs.canary.tools/guide/getting-started.html#hello-birds

Comment: You are using `json.loads()` but should be using `json.dumps()`. You can skip this and just use `y = r.text`

Comment: You're doing too much :-) `r.json()` already decoded the json for you, so you would either write `y=r.json()` directly, or `response_json=r.text` if you really-really wanted to call `json.loads()` yourself.